# Thunderbird 3.0 - how to prevent thread from collapsing when I read first mail in the thread?

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

When I read the first email in a threaded group of emails, the thread collapses in the main window pane (not sure what the heck it's called).  This occurred in T-Bird 2.x as well, but 3.0 now wants to delete the whole thread when I delete the first message in a collapsed thread, so it's now annoying to the point that I'm ready to switch back to 2.x (which will be a royal PITA if I have to do it).  How can I prevent T-Bird from collapsing the thread whenever I read the first message?  If it matters, I have T-Bird configured to always open the email in a new window.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm ready to dump TB altogether, the developers certainly have abandoned the KISS principle with version 3. at the moment i'm testing Koma-Mail portable, and i'm quite impressed. http://www.koma-code.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=5&Itemid=39

Comment: I need an Ubuntu solution.  I like the cat in the pictures, though!

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you open the config editor and set mail.operate_on_msgs_in_collapsed_threads to false

Comment: At least I won't delete the whole thread -- my sanity thanks you!